# When getting user video stream my webcam powers on but the video stream doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, artificial-intelligence

I am following this tutorial on face-api.js: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVClHLwv-4I
But when I start the code my webcam says it's working but it doesn't display in the browser. When I inspect it in chrome it says: Name: unable to play media.

Code (not including the API):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="face-api.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video" width="720" height="560" autoplay muted></video>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
  document.body.append(canvas)
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height }
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
  }, 100)
})
```

Comment: I've had this happen from time to time where the requested resolution of the webcam is higher than will actually work due to lack of USB bandwidth.  Although in your case, you're not specifying constraints at all... which should pretty much always work.  You might try setting a frame size of 640x480, just to see what happens.